# Pullback of 1-form $\omega$ to $U\subset\mathbb{CP}^1\setminus \{N\}$ modulo Stereographic Projection

Tags: complex-analysis, differential-geometry, differential-forms, complex-geometry, projective-geometry

> Let $f:\mathbb{CP}^1\setminus \{N\} \to \mathbb{C}$ be the stereographic projection of the complex projective line onto the complex plane. Similarly, let $U\subset\mathbb{C}$ be a closed rectangle. Consider a 1-form $\omega=g(z)dz$ defined strictly on $U,$ then how would the pullback $f^{*}\omega$ on a proper subset of $\mathbb{CP}^1$ (Namely the preimage of $U$) be computed explicitly?

*Attempted Solution*: We introduce spherical coordinates on $\Sigma$ (the Riemann sphere), i.e. the latitude $\phi,$ measured from the equator and ranging from $0$ to $\pi/2$ in the northern hemisphere and from $0$ to $-\pi/2$ in the southern hemisphere, and the longitude $\lambda,$ measured from the prime meridian (more exactly, from the point of intersection of the prime meridian with the positive $x$-axis) and ranging from $0$ to $\pi$ (including $\pi$) in the eastern hemisphere and from $0$ to $-\pi$ (excluding $-\pi$) in the western hemisphere. Under stereographic projection, we have $$argz=\lambda,|z|=tan\left(\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{\phi}{2}\right).$$ Therefore, the point of the sphere with coordinates $\lambda$ and $\phi$ is the image of the complex number $$z(\lambda,\phi)=tan\left(\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{\phi}{2}\right)(cos\lambda+isin\lambda),$$ i.e. the preimage of $z$ under $f:\mathbb{CP}^1\to \mathbb{C}.$ The 1-form $\omega$ can be written locally on $U$ as $\omega=g(z)dz.$ Consequently, the pullback on $\mathbb{CP}^1$ induced by $f$ is $$f^{*}\omega=g(f)\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial \phi}d\phi+\frac{\partial f}{\partial\lambda}d\lambda\right)\equiv\frac{g(f)}{2}sec^2\left(\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{\phi}{2}\right)(cos\lambda+isin\lambda)d\phi+ig(f)tan\left(\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{\phi}{2}\right)(cos\lambda+isin\lambda)d\lambda.$$

Is this computation correct? Thanks in advance. I would also like to acknowledge Ted Shifrin for his help in reformulating this question.

Comment: There is no diffeomorphism from $S^2$ to a rectangle. Are you sure that is what you meant?

Comment: That is my mistake. @AreaMan

Comment: There is still no diffeomorphism onto the plane... do you mean just a smooth map? It's going to be hard to compute something explicitly unless you choose a particular map. Or perhaps you mean something like: computing the pullback of $g(z) dz$ to $CP^1 \setminus {N}$ via stereographic projection?

Comment: Yes, this is what I meant to say. @AreaMan

Comment: There is no such thing as expressing explicitly a differential form on an abstract manifold. You can take a fixed local chart and then express that explicitly on that chart. But you have a chart already......

Comment: The main trick for doing these computations is that the $d$ operator commutes with pullback. So to compute, for example, $g^* dx$ just compute $g^*(x) = x(g)$ and then compute $d$. I guess you want to choose a different patch on the sphere than the north pole stereographic projection, since otherwise you will end up writing down a tautology.

Comment: If you want practice writing down the explicit behavior of differentials, it is probably best to write some polynomial maps from $R^2 \to R^2$ and compute the pullbacks of $dx$ and $dy$. The answer will look pretty familiar...

Comment: I understand conceptually what the pullback is doing. However, the problem  I have is with writing $\pi$ explicitly as a function of $\xi\in\mathbb{CP}^1.$ @AreaMan

Comment: @Multivariablecalculus How are you coordinatizing the sphere? I'd suggest first figuring out how to write down the stereographic projection for the sphere as a subset of $R^3$, the vectors of length one.

Comment: I have added my attempt at defining the pullback under stereographic projection in the above text. @AreaMa

Comment: I am sorry to bother you again, but does this seem correct? @AreaMan

Comment: I will try to get back to you later today. I am really busy right now. It's good practice to get used to checking your own work though

Comment: Okay, I understand. Thank you. @AreaMan